# Select a QRCODE out of possible options avaliable

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I don't know how to achieve my aim, I want your help.

After creating 5 different options of `Qr Code` images on a sheet of paper, a User is expected to select a single QR Code from the lot.

My Question
Is there a way to indicate to the `QR Scanner` the selected QR Code out of the lot?

Maybe the User tick their option `Qr Code` or any other method used so that the scanner can pick only the selected QrCode.

Comment: Please give more details about your question. Is it Java? C#? Assembly? Malbolge?

Comment: @MarceloVinícius using an android app if possible